# How to keep nth word of a cell

Tags: excel

I want to keep second word of all the cells in a column. Is this possible? I want to do this without using reference.

```
Column1
hi hello
you me
zero ten
stack overflow
```

Notice it is just one column. I want to tun this column into:

```
Column1
hello
me
ten
overflow
```

Is this something possible? I know how to do it using additional column as reference but not sure how to this job all in one column. I'd appreciate for help.

Comment: lets say that hi Hello is in Cell F8.  You could use a formula to extract it in the adjacent cell:  =MID(F8,FIND(" ", F8,1)+1,LEN(F8))

Answer (score 1):

Without using an extra column, you could do it with **VBA.**  Select the cells you wish to process and run this small macro:

```
Sub SecondWord()
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, " ") > 0 Then
            r.Value = Split(r.Value, " ")(1)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: im stunned. Did not know excel can do such thing. I appreciate it. =D